# i want to validate CNIC number in WPF 13 digits and 2 dashes

Tags: c#, wpf

CNIC number is a String containing 13 digits and two dashes 
for example 11111-1111111-1 . how i can implement this in validation in Wpf

Comment: Regex is your friend; well, maybe not, but this is probably what you need at any rate.

Comment: We need alot more information to give you a good answer. Are you using a MVVM pattern, does your model Implement INotifyDataErrorInfo ?

Comment: no i am using IDataErrorInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method

```
private bool IsValidCNIC(string cnic)
    {
        Regex check = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}$");
        bool valid = false;
        valid = check.IsMatch(cnic);
        return valid;
    }
```